# Emacs home directory

Tags: file, emacs, windows-10, environment-variables, customization

Many commands access files, and they usually take a path relative to `~/` which I gather is the "home" directory. In my case, `C:\Users\Grant\AppData\Roaming\` which is where `.emacs.d\` and my init files live.

This is great for Emacs, but not as useful for me. I typically would be over in `C:\Users\Grant\Documents\` or my Python script files directory.

Also, I'm using `Customize` and typing in absolute file names for things like Org capture templates (currently anything I capture goes into files in one particular directory). Not that it's likely that these locations will change, but I was wondering if there are variables I can set for these places, which I can use in `Customize` or when invoking `Dired` - maybe some sort of environment variable? And if so, how can I refer to them when typing in a file name?

Comment: Can't you set your `HOME` enviroment variable on windows and use that (eg. `(setenv "HOME" "<path/to/home>")`).  I also set a bunch of `defconst`s for my common locations in init, eg, `(defconst my/work (expand-file-name "work" (getenv "HOME"))` and reference those as roots for expansion in other code.

Comment: jenesaisquoi: I figured that Emacs needs to know the location that ~/ is currently pointing to, so I didn't want to try changing it. I'm not familiar with defconst - I'll look into it. Thank you

Comment: it is just a way to define a variable in lisp like `defvar`, etc.

Comment: What @jenesaisquoi said (please put that in an answer, jenesais). Set your `HOME` env var in Windows and life will be easy: then just use `~/`.

Comment: I don't think defconst (or variables generally) are going to be useful for entering file path strings in the Customize UI.

Comment: @phils good point, I don't really use the customize UI so hadn't been thinking on the  right track.

Comment: @Drew I think there was a duplicate I saw earlier but now I can't find it.  There seem to be a lot of answers scattered around like here - https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/a6ka23/change_home_folder_location_windows/

Comment: I've tried changing `HOME` to `C:\Users\Grant` and found that Emacs made a new `.emacs.d` there so I have to compare the files there to the originals in `AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d`. Not sure if I should just move all of `C:\Users\Grant\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d` to `C:\Users\Grant\.emacs.d`, or if Emacs will still try to find stuff in the `Roaming` directory.

Comment: It will find use the first found -- the manual will explicitly explain the order of preference for the locations.  You could always just symlink